# Restoring specific Sqlite Database to Android

Tags: android, sqlite, restore

I can back up and restore my most recent database OK but I want to save a time stamped Sqlite database like "back_up_12_11_17_13_32". This is so the user can restore not just the most recent back up but whatever back up he needs.

I'm wondering how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

### Here's some pointers/techniques that I've utilised for what I believe is quite a flexible backup/restore facility.

I use the following to create the backup name.

```
private void setFullFilename() {
    backupfullfilename.setText(
            backupbasepart.getText().toString() +
            backupdatetimepart.getText().toString() +
            backupextension.getText().toString()
    );
}
```

where

- backupbasepart defaults to **ShopWiseDB**
- backupdatetimepart defaults to  the current time (when activity is started) in YYMMDDhhmm format as obtained via :-

  ```
  Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
  return "_" + sdf.format(cldr.getTime());
  ```
- backupextension defaults to **.bkp**
- Noting that I allow all to be edited.

The App's backup/restore activity looks like :-

[image]

- Note that the Spinner has been clicked to show the list of available backups and to also show how the timestamp is also converted to a more human readable format.
  All backups are stored in **PRIMARY PUBLIC EXTERNAL STORAGE** (user has the option to copy/move to wherever) in the Download directory in a sub directory called ShopWise (this is fixed to simplify matters i.e. to not have to write a file explorer)

Using this directory also allows databases to be copied from other sources, so users could share databases if they so wished or this ability could be used for problem determination and resolution.

What backups shown in the Restore Spinner are determined by the 3 inputs that allows some flexibility - by default only standard backups are listed. However, blanking out the Base Filename will result in all files (well all that have an extension of .bkp (The File extension only shows files with that extension, blanking it out shows all extensions)).

e.g. if all are blanked out then all then you could have :-

[image]

When it boils down to it the core code for providing the list of restoreable files is :-

```
private void populateRestoreSpinner(Spinner spn,
                                    TextView tv,
                                    String basefilename,
                                    String fileext,
                                    StoreData sd,
                                    TextView restorebutton) {
    int fcount = 0;
    ArrayList<File> reverseflist = new ArrayList<>();

    //
    sd = new StoreData(getResources().getString(R.string.backupdirectoryname),"xxx",true);
    sd.refreshOtherFilesInDirectory();

    // Build the File ArrayList
    ArrayList<File> flst = new ArrayList<>(sd.getFilesInDirectory());

    // Ascertain the relevant files that are needed for the restore backup
    // file selector
    for(int i = 0; i < flst.size(); i++) {
        boolean endingok = flst.get(i).getName().endsWith(fileext);
        boolean containsok = flst.get(i).getName().contains(basefilename);
        if((strictbackupmode && endingok && containsok)
                || (!strictbackupmode && (endingok || containsok))) {
            fcount++;
        } else {
            flst.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // Reverse the order of the list so most recent backups appear first
    // Also hide/show the Restore button and spinner according to if
    // files exist or not
    // (doing nothing in the case where the is no restore button i.e.
    //  null has been passed)
    if(flst.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = (flst.size() -1); i >= 0; i--) {
            reverseflist.add(flst.get(i));
        }
        if (restorebutton != null) {
            spn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            restorebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        if (restorebutton != null) {
            spn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            restorebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Set the available count for display
    //String bcnt = "Available Backups=" + Integer.toString(reverseflist.size());
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(reverseflist.size()));

    // Set the spinner adapter and dropdown layout and then set the
    // spinner's adapter
    AdapterFileList afl = new AdapterFileList(this,
            R.layout.filelist,
            reverseflist,
            getIntent());
    afl.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.filelist);
    spn.setAdapter(afl);
}
```

Note! StoreData is a glorified File/Directory listing that's pretty long winded but basically has members such as :-

```
private String directory;
private String subdirectory;
private String filename;
private boolean mounted;
private boolean inerror;
private boolean fileexists;
private boolean direxists;
private long errorcode;
private ArrayList<String> errorlist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<File> otherfilesindirectory = new ArrayList<>();
```